Most efficient way to fill holes in an object?

I'm trying to remove holes from the complex object above. (It is a wall with 46 oval cutouts). The front and back planes of the object are connected by the vertices that make the hole, so it's more of a tunnel in that sense.
It's taken me a decent amount of time just to fill these 5 holes. Is there a more efficient way than what I have been doing? Here is my process:

Select the first vertex that can loop around (green), select edge loops, and delete.
Starting at the next outer vertex (red), repeat this 4 times.
Repeat on the other side.
Select the remaining disconnect vertices on the inside (yellow), and delete.
Connect all vertices to create a face, on each side.


I apologize in advance if I have worded anything insufficiently. I'm very new to Blender.
Images of the entire wall:



Shift +Z will take you a view where you could select vertices on both sides in same click as long as the object is aligned to XYZ one of the coordinates.
+
Once you select the yellow vertices, Control and + should select the green and red automatically
Could you add a screengrab of the larger geometry these two walls are a part of?
Because I feel making a new wall is easier

That technique worked amazingly, thank you! I've added screengrabs of the entire shape to the original post.
